# Need help understanding java linked list putAfter() method

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

An element in the chain that comprises a LinkedList. 
Note: the operations of this class manage the relationship between a Link and its neighbors.
The LinkedList is responsible for keeping tract of the head and tail of the list.

```
public class Link<Item> {
    private final Item item;
    private Link<Item> next;
    private Link<Item> prev;
```

Insert this Link into a list after a given Link.
@param before is the given Link.

```
public final void putAfter (Link<Item> before) {
    prev = before;
    if (null == before) return;
    next = before.next;
    before.next = this;
    if (null != next) 
        next.prev = this;
}
```

Comment: This code won't work - did you test it ? (hint: you need `while()` loop)

Answer (score 1):

You have made a basic mistake in the coding of the method<sup>1</sup>.

You can find it by:

- reading your code and "executing" it in your head ... or with a pencil and paper, or
- running it in a debugger and single-stepping the method to see what each statement is actually doing.

We could tell you what your mistake is, but you will learn to program better if you try to find the problem yourself.  That will make you a better programmer in the long run ... and that's what **we want**<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Based on the nature of the method you are writing, I am assuming that this is some kind of learning exercise.  If that was not the case, my answer would have been different ...</sup>

<sup>2 - And to be clear, I do not condone doing other peoples' homework for them.  It is in *nobody's* interest in the long term.</sup>

Comment: The method works. This is one method of about 40 that i have to remember for a test next week. I just wanted someone to describe what each line of code does so I can better understand what is going on. It would be easier for me to replicate this method on a test if I understand every detail of this method.